# Offline video viewing feature like Netflix and YouTube

Tags: youtube, video-streaming, netflix

I have an LMS developed in PHP and using video.js for delivering recorded lectures to students. Students are facing slow buffering issues due to the distant location of dedicated server. I want to add a feature where students can download the video for offline viewing just like Netflix and YouTube. Is it possible to add this feature in a website? If yes, can anyone please guide me towards some library to implement this feature.

I Have transcoded the videos into ABR with 4 different resolutions but still the slow buffering issue is there.